# Genymotion does not show all API versions

Tags: android, sdk, genymotion

I am finally giving Genymotion a try. And I have to say: its amazing!

The problem is that when I try to create a new virtual device, and click the `Android version` dropdown, I only see the following versions:

[image]

I'd like to test my app on versions not listed here.

Where is Genymotion picking these values? If its checking the sdk installation, why isn't it showing more api versions? The following prtscr shows part of the sdk manager window (right-click and open in new tab for legible viewing). I have installed many api versions but somehow, Genymotion shows only a subset of these:

[image]

I have also setup the path to sdk in `Settings / ADB / Use custom Android SDK tools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genymotion is not based on your local installed SDK apis as Google enviroment is, so it offers a subset of own designed device oriented Android SDKs. It has obvious performance advantages, and even you can test real Google Play Store experiences (which you can't over Google's emulators) but offers a more limited set of SDKs. I always suggest to keep both enviroments up to date at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your input. How is it that such information isn't available on genymotion's guide/site. And just to confirm, your installation of genymotion(I assume you're using it) shows the same 5 android versions?

Comment: Yes, I have the very same 5 versions. I agree, Genymotion docs are not in full detail about this, but as I'm a very early user I was not surprised because the Genymotion versions policy seems to be to increase slowly only when SDKs became stable and popular. Personally, I think it is useful when I need to test something quickly in a realistic way. But, for example, until Android L comes to mainstream I'm painfully and slowly studying it from Google's emulators. :)

Comment: I really appreciate this. Somehow, I wasn't being able to wrap my head around the limited version coverage. Its beyond compare already, and I sure hope that the coverage expands soon. One last bother: has the version list changed any in the time you've been using genymotion?

Comment: Yes, of course, it began with only 2.3 and it was slowly progressing from there. But as I previously commented, I've think that they're more focused in offer you a fast and stable emulator than multiple cutting edge versions.